# open gedit with shell script and then do another process after closing gedit

Tags: shell, file, gedit

I have the following script

```
echo "Please Specify the Name of the file"
read file

echo "Please copy and paste the information into ${file}     and press save and close."
gedit ${file}

echo "You now have ${file} to be processed"
```

How do I tweak the script so that the phrase "You now have ${file} to be processed" does not display until I close the gedit window?

Comment: May be `gedit ${file} && echo "You now have ${file} to be processed"`

Comment: gedit --wait "$file"